# Call function on post approve

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm a little stuck.
I'm a php beginner constantly learning and now I face a new challenge on Wordpress.
There are a few authors on the same site.
When someone writes a new post, it goes in "Pending Review" and it is shown on page only when the "Administrator" approves it.

The point is that I need to call a custom PHP function whenever the "Administrator" approves a post and I'm not really sure how to do this. The function is simple, like update other tables with some of the author's info. The problem is I don't know how exactly to run it on post approval.

Yes, a workaround would be a CRON function to run once an hour or so but it's not really what I need.

Quick update: By "Administrator approves" I mean he checks each post and changed its status from "Pending review" to "Published" and hits the Save button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `hook` for example:

```
function on_publish_pending_post( $post ) {
    // A function to perform when a pending post is published.
}
add_action(  'pending_to_publish',  'on_publish_pending_post', 10, 1 );
```

More information on [post status transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

Comment: Thank you very much! Someone also suggested me to use hooks but it was not very clear to me (as I'm a fairly beginner) but I'll read it. If you can suggest me more relevant info please do, I feel a bit lost googling around as I'm constantly unsure if I found what I need or not :))

Comment: This function will run when a user with the necessary permissions change the status of a post from pending to publish. You can access which post it is by `$post`. Using $post you can access the author's ID and get more information about them. Easiest way to get started is to put this piece of code in your theme's `functions.php`. Then all you have to do is enter your logic for updating the other tables.

Comment: A hook can be described as a way to use your own functions with Wordpress core functionality. You can place a hook inside a plugin or a theme, e.g. the functions.php file. So if you place that code that  nanodanger wrote inside your themes functions.php file, you have access to the $post object and can change the content of it.

Comment: Actually your 2 replies answered like 10 of my questions so thanks a lot! That was more clear than I ever expected!